# Yii - loop an array from findAll

Tags: yii, findall

I'm trying to implement `for` loop to update time.

```
$files = File::model()->findAll('type="A" AND id='.$id);    
    function files($files,$limit=null){
        $limit = isset($limit) ? $limit : count($files);
        for($i=0;$i<=$limit;$i++){
            $files[$i]->date = date('Y:m:d H:i:s');
            $files[$i]->update();
        }
    }
```

This function return error `undefined offset 1`.

What is the result of findAll method? Is it a multidimensional array of records? And How could I fixed this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are setting `$limit` to `count($files)` but using `$i<=$limit` in your loop. Should be `<` instead.

```
for($i=0; $i<$limit; $i++){
```

Since there is a chance of an external `$limit` being applied you could use a `foreach` loop with a conditional `break`.

```
foreach($files as $a => $file) {
    if($a == $limit) {
        break;
    }
    $file->date = date('Y:m:d H:i:s');
    $file->update();
}
```

Note that `findAll()` without a `limit` retrieves all the records from the databases for that table. Perhaps you should consider adding the limit through [`CDbCriteria`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria)

Comment: As your suggestion, I've edited `$limit = isset($limit) ? $limit : count($files)-1`. But nothing changed. This error still occurs.

Comment: I've found out this issue. It happens when some conditions are set. I have conditional and non-conditional findAll either. It caused my misunderstanding at the first time. I've edited my question. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: First check whether `$files` is empty before the loop.

Comment: I've check variable `$files` with `var_dump($files)`. And all keys are listed correctly. However, when I try `var_dump($files[$key]) // $key can be whatever number exists`. This error occurs. Kind of weird error ~~.